# Returing a list object from a function

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to write a function that returns a series of ggplot scatterplots from a data frame. Below is a reproducible data frame as well as the function I've written

```
a <- sample(0:20,20,rep=TRUE)
b <- sample(0:300,20,rep=TRUE)
c <- sample(0:3, 20, rep=TRUE)
d <- rep("dog", 20) 

df <- data.frame(a,b,c,d)

loopGraph <- function(dataFrame, y_value, x_type){
  if(is.numeric(dataFrame[,y_value]) == TRUE && x_type == "numeric"){
dataFrame_number <- dataFrame %>%
  dplyr::select_if(is.numeric) %>% 
  filter(y_value!=0) %>%  
  dplyr::select(-y_value)
x <- 1
y<-ncol(dataFrame_number)
endList <- list()
for (i in x:y)
  {
    i
    x_value <-colnames(dataFrame_number)[i]
    plotDataFrame <- cbind(dataFrame_number[,x_value], dataFrame[,y_value]) %>% as.data.frame()
    r2 <- summary(lm(plotDataFrame[,2]~plotDataFrame[,1]))$r.squared
    ggplot <- ggplot(plotDataFrame, aes(y=plotDataFrame[,2],x=plotDataFrame[,1])) +
      geom_point()+
      geom_smooth(method=lm) +
      labs(title = paste("Scatterplot of", y_value, "vs.", x_value), subtitle= paste0("R^2=",r2), x = x_value,y=y_value)        
    endList[[i]] <- ggplot
}
  return(endList) 
}
  else{print("Try again")}
}
loopGraph(df, "a", "numeric")
```

What I want is to return the object `endList` so I can look at the multiple scatterplots generated by this function. What happens is that the function prints each scatterplot in the plots window without giving me access to the `endList` object.

How can I get this function to return the endList object? Is there a better way to go about this? Thanks in advance!

**Update**

Thanks to @GordonShumway for solving my first issue. Now, when I define plots as `plots <- loopGraph(df, "a", "numeric")`, I can view all the outputs. However, all the graphs are of the first ggplot feature, even though the labels change. Any intuition as to why this is happening? Or how to fix it? I tried adding `dev.set(dev.next())` to no avail.

Comment: Just assign the result to a variable `plots <- loopGraph(df,"a", "numeric")`

Comment: @GordonShumway wow ... that was extremely dumb of me. Thank you!